# Getting "Cannot read property 'instant' of undefined" when using ngx-translate (TranslateService) whitin a service

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular-module, angular-lazyloading

I'm trying to translate via component, because I intend to use the translation in a sweetAlert pop up. I'm getting "Cannot read property 'instant' of undefined" though. I'd like to understand where I'm mistaken.

**Note:** I'm using lazy load modules

AppModule

```
imports: [
    ..., // for short
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
    })
  ],
```

My service where I'm trying to use TranslateService

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class UtilsService {
constructor(
    private alertMsg: ToastrService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private storage: StorageService,
    private translate: TranslateService
  ) {

  }
}


showAlertRequestError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    debugger
    let erroMsgTranslated: string;
    switch (err.status) {
      case 500:
      case 404:
        erroMsgTranslated = this.translate.instant('STATUSCODEMESSAGES.CLIENTERRORS.404')
        Toast.fire(erroMsgTranslated, ` Message: ${err.message}. Status: ${err.status}`, 'error');
        break;
      case 400: 
        Toast.fire('', ` Message: ${err.error.error}. Status: ${err.status}`, 'info');
        break;
      case 408:
        erroMsgTranslated = this.translate.instant('STATUSCODEMESSAGES.CLIENTERRORS.408')
        Toast.fire(erroMsgTranslated, ` Message: ${err.error.error}. Status: ${err.status}`, 'warning');
        break;
      default:
        Toast.fire(`${err.message},`, `Stats: ${err.status}`, 'warning')
    }
  }
```

Comment: please, show the code where `showAlertRequestError` is called. I bet the error is there

Comment: are you using the SahredModule?